# Azure Billing API returns nothing

Tags: c#, api, azure, billing

I want to read current charges of my Azure Subscription programmatically. I currently use the sources from Microsofts [GitHub samples](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples).

I added an application to my AAD and gave it all permissions on 2 areas:

[image: Permissions]

I configured my subscription id and the client id of the app. When I try to get the charges with the following url:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Subscription-ID}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2015-07-01+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2015-08-31+00%3a00%3a00Z
```

This link queries 2 months but returns nothing. My Azure portal gives me current charges.

Comment: I have seen issues where Usage API erroring out when the end date specified is in future. Please try by specifying an end date that has not happened e.g. start date = 1st July and end date 14th July.

Comment: Changing it to 2015-07-15 does not help. I also reduced the time frame by selecting 2015-07-10 to 2015-07-15 which doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah...I should have seen it sooner. I just realized that you're fetching data for last year. Billing and Usage data is only kept for last 3 months (90 days to be precise) and because of this you're not getting any data back.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me, if there is any possibility to obtain prices too? I can only see the consumption infos but there is no price information.

Comment: Sure you can! You would need to use Rate Card API to get the pricing information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx. In order to calculate the total consumption, you would need to combine these two. HTH.